# How to solve the following Linear Equation question?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Find the value of *h* if the line joining (2,h) and (4,9) and the line y=3x+4 are:

- Parallel

I tried to do this for the Parallel

$$H=3(2)+ 4$$ to find H

I got 
$$H=10$$

But I don't think that was the answer. How would I solve this?

and what if it's

- Perpendicular?

Comment: btw, is $h$ and $H$ the same object? $(2,h)$ need not lie on the line $y=3x+4$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. The slope of the line joining $(2,h)$ and $(4,9)$ is $\frac{9-h}{4-2}.$
2. If two lines are parallel, they share the same slope.
3. If a line has non-zero gradient, $m$, then line perpendicular to it has gradient $\frac{-1}{m}$.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: If they are parallel, do you see that both lines share the same gradient, 3? Hence for the parallel case, you have to solve $\frac{9-h}{4-2}=3$

Comment: if they are parallel they have the same slope right? What do you mean by gradient? How did you get 3?

Comment: when you see the word "gradient" in this current answer, replace it by "slope". For a line $y=mx+c$, $m$ is the slope. Hence, I obtain $3$ this way.

Comment: How would you get 3 though? like $$9-h/4-2$$ isn't that $$9-h/2$$, how is it 3?

Comment: $3$ is obtained from $y=3x+4$ and you have to solve for $h$ from $\frac{9-h}{2}=3$

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the line joining $(2,h)$ and $(4,9)$ is:
$$
m=\frac{9-h}{4-2}=\frac{9-h}{2}
$$

and two lines are parallel if they have the same slope and are orthogonal if their slopes are such that their product is $-1$

So, in your case:

$\frac{9-h}{2}=3$ for parallel lines and $\frac{9-h}{2}=-\frac{1}{3}$ for orthogonal lines.

Comment: How did you solve when H was not given

Comment: Can you solve for $h$ the two equations?

Comment: but how do you get 3? H is not given right? what is orthologonal lines? is there a simpler way for this?

Comment: $3$ is the slope ( or gradient) of the line $y=3x+4$ ( that is given) and $-1/3$ is the slope of a line perpendicular ( or orthogonal, it is the same) to this line.

Comment: Oh, it was that simple, I just had to look at the given slope?

Comment: Yes!  You  want a parallel to a **given** line  and this means the same slope of this line. :)